# Реализация шаблона одиночка в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

В общем, нужно как-то организовать доступ к общим данным, которые я получаю из БД, для всех скриптов. Как лучше это сделать?

Читал про синглтон, но не понял, как его правильно использовать, для чего он нужен на примере юнити?

Обязательно ли он должен висеть на игровом объекте? Требуется хранить достаточно много полей.

Примеры желательно писать на C#.

Answer (score 1):

Принципиально подход использования шаблона "одиночка" (singleton) в Unity ничем не отличается от стандартного подхода. Самое главное - это учесть время жизни объекта. В Unity можно выделить два срока жизни объектов:

**1. Время жизни программы**.

```
public class GameResourceManger
{
        private static GameResourceManger instance;

        private static GameResourceManger()
        {
        }

        public static GameResourceManger GetInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new GameResourceManger();
            return instance;
        }
}
```

**2. Время жизни сцены**. В этом случае следует использовать объект сцены и добавить к нему скрипт.

```
public class GameResourceManger : MonoBehaviour
{
        private static GameResourceManger instance;

        public void Awake()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        public static GameResourceManger GetInstance()
        {
            return instance;
        }
}
```

Использование в обоих случаях будет одинаковое.

```
var instance = GameResourceManger.GetInstance();
```

В чем же разница? Разница в том, что если вы используете повторную загрузку сцены, то в случае первого подхода ваш класс не будет инициализирован повторно (экземпляра класса будет уничтожен после выхода из `main`). Во втором же подходе Unity управляет временем жизни объектов. Данное утверждение также справедливо и в случаях, когда вы подгружаете следующую сцену - в случае первого подхода, новый менеджер ресурсов не будет создан, вместо этого будет использоваться предыдущий объект.

Повторюсь, наглядно с этим можно столкнуться в случае повторной загрузки сцены (переиграть уровень). В этом случае все объекты сцены будут новыми (и, соответственно, будут созданы новые объекты всех классов скриптов добавленных к объектам сцены), а ваш менеджер, в случае первого подхода, останется прежним, зачастую содержащим ссылки на предыдущие экземпляры.

Answer (score 0):

А что вы подразумеваете под БД? В идеале работать с [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM), это когда любой записи в БД соответствует некий объект в программе. Например [Fluent NHibernate и Oracle](http://habrahabr.ru/post/125135/). Это если именно с БД работать надо, а если требуется только получить доступ к общим данным вроде количество набранных очков, галочку что куплен статус и т.п. то тогда да действительно проще через singletone. Создается статик объект

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton singleton;
    public int Score = 0;
    public bool isVIP = false;

    private MySingleton()
    {
    }

    public static MySingleton GetInstance()
    {
        // для исключения возможности создания двух объектов 
        // при многопоточном приложении
        if (singleton == null)
        {
            lock (typeof(MySingleton))
            {
                if (singleton == null)
                    singleton = new MySingleton();
            }
        }

        return singleton;
    }
}
```

для того чтобы с ним работать в любом месте программы делаем так

```
MySingleton.GetInstance().Score += 50; // вот мы добавили очки
MySingleton.GetInstance().isVIP = true; // перевели в режим VIP
```

Только надо учитывать, что вопросы по сохранению и загрузке значений на ваших плечах.

Вешать синглтон на игровой объект вовсе не обязательно.  Я делаю класс наследник от MonoBehaivour в качестве интерфейса для доступа к синглтону только в случае если хочу получить какой то интерфейс для работы с ним через Editor.

У меня в одном из проектов была задача хранить настройки для запуска программы в разных режимах. Сделал Объект установок `Setups`, в нем создал массив с объектами `Setup`. Каждая настройка содержала все необходимые поля ну и какое то поле с индексом для поиска. Далее делаем `Setups` и `Setup` сериализуемыми объектами. Одному из объектов создаем переменную Setups и вот вы получили средствами юнити базу данных с объектами. Или вставляете такую ссылку на `Setups` в синглтон и с помощью любого удобного сериализатора которых можно найти море в AssetStore делаете загрузку этого объекта при открытии приложения и сохранение при его закрытии.

Вот пример как делается [БД средствами Unity](http://burgzergarcade.net/scriptableobjects-as-databases-in-unity/).

Comment: Как написано по ссылке ниже, данное решение не самое правильное: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx Таже самое относится к локу на инстансе типа