# Как использовать переменную из одного скрипта в другом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Например есть две сцены, Scene1 и Scene2
В Scene1 есть скрипт Script1, в котором есть переменная root, весит на объекте rt, а в Scene2 есть скрипт Script2.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как использовать переменную root в скрипте Script2??

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
Script1 myscript;
void Start()
{
myscript = GameObject.Find("rt").GetComponent<Script1> ();
}
}
```

Такой код не срабатывает, видимо где то нужно еще учитывать сцену, подскажите пожалуйста как решить такую проблему??

Answer (score 1):

[Реализация шаблона одиночка в Unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420898/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-unity3d)

Принципиально подход использования шаблона "одиночка" (singleton) в Unity ничем не отличается от стандартного подхода. Самое главное - это учесть время жизни объекта. В Unity можно выделить два срока жизни объектов:

**1. Время жизни программы**.

```
public class GameResourceManger
{
        private static GameResourceManger instance;

        private static GameResourceManger()
        {
        }

        public static GameResourceManger GetInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new GameResourceManger();
            return instance;
        }
}
```

**2. Время жизни сцены**. В этом случае следует использовать объект сцены и добавить к нему скрипт.

```
public class GameResourceManger : MonoBehaviour
{
        private static GameResourceManger instance;

        public void Awake()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        public static GameResourceManger GetInstance()
        {
            return instance;
        }
}
```

Использование в обоих случаях будет одинаковое.

```
var instance = GameResourceManger.GetInstance();
```

В чем же разница? Разница в том, что если вы используете повторную загрузку сцены, то в случае первого подхода ваш класс не будет инициализирован повторно (экземпляра класса будет уничтожен после выхода из `main`). Во втором же подходе Unity управляет временем жизни объектов. Данное утверждение также справедливо и в случаях, когда вы подгружаете следующую сцену - в случае первого подхода, новый менеджер ресурсов не будет создан, вместо этого будет использоваться предыдущий объект.

Повторюсь, наглядно с этим можно столкнуться в случае повторной загрузки сцены (переиграть уровень). В этом случае все объекты сцены будут новыми (и, соответственно, будут созданы новые объекты всех классов скриптов добавленных к объектам сцены), а ваш менеджер, в случае первого подхода, останется прежним, зачастую содержащим ссылки на предыдущие экземпляры.

**Можно сделать так:**

Если требуется только получить доступ к общим данным вроде количество набранных очков, галочку что куплен статус и т.п. то тогда да действительно проще через singletone. Создается статик объект

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton singleton;
    public int Score = 0;
    public bool isVIP = false;

    private MySingleton()
    {
    }

    public static MySingleton GetInstance()
    {
        // для исключения возможности создания двух объектов 
        // при многопоточном приложении
        if (singleton == null)
        {
            lock (typeof(MySingleton))
            {
                if (singleton == null)
                    singleton = new MySingleton();
            }
        }

        return singleton;
    }
}
```

для того чтобы с ним работать в любом месте программы делаем так

```
MySingleton.GetInstance().Score += 50; // вот мы добавили очки
MySingleton.GetInstance().isVIP = true; // перевели в режим VIP
```

**Вот ещё:**

[Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)